# MySQL - Double connection on two Databases?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, max, connection

This is just a quick question, I couldn't find it on the internet, but I did wanted to have a confirmation.

Say that if I, using PHP, want to connect to *(for both the same)* MySQL server, but I want to use two databases, *not tables*. Because you can connect to only one MySQL-database in the PHP `mysqli_connect()` command, will, connecting to two databases, though on the same server, use two connections.

Because then it'll probably go fast with the `max_connections`, right?

*P.S. What was the SQL-command again to see the `mac_connections` value again? I thought it started with `GET GLOBAL ...` or something, but I might be wrong.
I do not have access to the server, only to (limited) FTP files (it's a bit irritating).*

Comment: are the databases in the same server?

Comment: then i think you can use single connection and use database name in query like `SELECT database1.table.field, database2.table.field, ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found it, though I ran into it by pure accident [`mysqli_select_db()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_select_db.asp).

Comment: you don't want to run query across 2 databases?

Comment: @bansi what do you mean? I want to perform some queries on database 1, then switch to 2 to do some other queries and then switch back...

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%max_connections%'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have both databases in same server you can connect to the server and select one database. You can query from any other databases in the server as long as you have permission. Use the syntax `databasename.tablename.columnname` in your queries.

If your databases are in different server you may have to do little more work on the server side. you can use the [The FEDERATED Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html)

Comment: But this will only use one connection, as in `max_connections`?